# Bash shell argument passing...?

Tags: linux, bash

You can use a semicolon in bash shell to specify multiple commands.
Sometimes, one of those commands pops a question, requiring user input. (typically 'y' / 'n', or whatever really)
If I know what I want to answer in advance, is there a way to parse it to the commands somehow, like an argument, or some weird magical pipe stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any "weird magical pipe stuff", just a pipe.

```
./foo ; echo "y" | ./bar ; ./baz
```

Or magical [herestring](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput?#Heredocs_And_Herestrings) syntax if you prefer:

```
./foo ; ./bar <<<"y" ; ./baz
```

Comment: Excellent answers Mat, it works great.
It's all magical to me. :)

Comment: Btw, I know this is not the place for comments like this, but you are one of my absolute heroes... 0 asked questions, 98k points. I want to be like you when I grow up. Love, cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `yes` command to put a lot of 'y' 's to a pipe.

For example, if you want to remove all your text files, you can use

```
yes | rm -r *.txt
```

causing every question asked by rm being answered with a y.
If you want another default answer, you can give it as an argument to yes:

```
yes n | rm -r *.txt
```

This will output a 'n'.

For more information, see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 2):

For the simple "yes" answer there is a command [yes](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes), available on most Unix and Linux platforms:

```
$ yes | /bin/rm -i *
```

For an advanced protocol you may want to check the famous [Expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), also widely available. It needs basic knowledge of [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/).

Comment: Risky example! Also, there's the infamous behaviour of rm when your directory contains a file named -f ...

Comment: This is an example of `yes`, not an example of `rm`.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's not bash popping these questions. It is the particular program called (for instance, cp -i asks before overwriting files). Frequently those commands also have switches to answer the questions, like -y for fsck, or how -f overrides -i in rm. Many programs could be answered through a pipe, which is why we have the command "yes", but some go to extra lengths to ensure they cannot; for instance ssh when asking for passwords. Also, there's nothing magical about pipes. If the program only sometimes asks a question, and it matters what question, there are tools designed for that such as "expect".

In a typical shell script, when you do know exactly what you want to feed in and the program accepts input on stdin, you could handle it using a plain pipe:

```
echo -e '2+2\n5*3' | bc
```

If it's a longer piece then a here document might be helpful:

```
bc <<EOF
2+2
3*5
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a command provides an option to set default answer to a question. One notable example is `apt-get` - a package manager for Debian/Ubuntu/Mint. It provides and options `-y`, `--yes`, `--assume-yes` to be used in non-interactive scripts.